# Compare hashMap arrays values with Javascript

Tags: javascript

How to compare between two Hashmaps that contains arrays in their values with javascript?

Example : Let suppose this is my 2 hashmaps

1st =>

```
1234 : [1.03 , 2.17 , 3] 
1235 : [1 , 4 , 5]
1236 : [2 , 3 , 3]
1237 : [0.33 , 1.51 , 5]
```

2nd =>

```
1234 : [1.03 , 2.17 , 3]
1235 : [1.17 , 2 , 3.9]
1236 : [2 , 3 , 3]
1237 : [2 , 1 , 5]
```

Result =>

```
1235 : [1 , 4 , 5]
1237 : [0.33 , 1.51 , 5]
```

(the goal is to compare the first with the second and display what keys and values of the first hashmap that aren't coherent).

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: Use cycles and comparison

Comment: Please, always add relevant code _inside the question itself_. Create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I did this at the beginning when my values was String and not arrays :

```
compareHashMap: function(iAdaptation, iActual){
                var difference = {};
                Object.keys(iActual).forEach(function(k){
                    if(iAdaptation[k] !== iActual[k]){
                        difference[k] = iActual[k];
                    }
                });
                return difference;
            },
```

P.S : iAdaptation and iActual are hashmaps

Comment: You should edit your question with this information, rather than add an answer.

Comment: However, the simplest change would be to use `JSON.stringify()` in your comparison. Such as: `if (JSON.stringify(iAdaptation[k]) !== JSON.stringify(iActual[k])) { ... }`.

Comment: @Phylogenesis result value should be an array and not a string, JSON.stringfy return a string

Comment: It only compares the stringified forms, it still adds the actual array to `difference`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const one = {1234: [1.03, 2.17, 3],1235: [1, 4, 5],1236: [2, 3, 3],1237: [0.33, 1.51, 5]};
const two = {1234: [1.03, 2.17, 3],1235: [1.17, 2, 3.9],1236: [2, 3, 3],1237: [2, 1, 5]};
const result = Object.keys(one)
  .filter(k => one[k].toString() !== two[k].toString())
  .map(k => ({[k]: one[k]}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: it didn't work :

TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
    at Object.keys.filter.k 
    at Array.filter (native)

Comment: In the code example is working as you can see.. Doble check your code please